# Invalid Hook Call. Using ReactJS in the admin section of WordPress (specifically editing a custom post type)

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, webpack, yarnpkg

I want to create a React based custom post type editor in WordPress. I've created a plugin that:

1. Registers a custom post type `my-custom-post`
2. Injects `<div id="root"></div>` into `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=my-custom-post`
3. Builds a simple React app that renders a component in `<div id="root"></div>`

**/wp-admin/plugins/my-custom-plugin/src/index.js**

```
const {
    useState
} = wp.element;

function Example(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(new Date());

    return <h1>Hello!</h1>;
}

render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById( 'root' )
);
```

**Dependencies**

```
λ yarn list --pattern react
yarn list v1.22.15
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements@7.17.6
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-display-name@7.16.7
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-development@7.16.7
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx@7.17.3
├─ @babel/plugin-transform-react-pure-annotations@7.16.7
├─ @babel/preset-react@7.16.7
├─ @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin@0.5.4
├─ @svgr/babel-plugin-transform-react-native-svg@5.4.0
├─ @types/react-dom@17.0.11
├─ @types/react@17.0.39
├─ @wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17@0.6.6
├─ enzyme-to-json@3.6.2
│  └─ react-is@16.13.1
├─ eslint-plugin-react-hooks@4.3.0
├─ eslint-plugin-react@7.29.0
├─ prop-types@15.8.1
│  └─ react-is@16.13.1
├─ react-date-object@2.1.5
├─ react-dom@17.0.2
├─ react-element-popper@2.1.6
├─ react-is@17.0.2
├─ react-multi-date-picker@3.3.0
├─ react-refresh@0.10.0
├─ react-shallow-renderer@16.14.1
├─ react-test-renderer@17.0.2
└─ react@17.0.2
```

**wp-content/plugins/my-custom-plugin/package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-custom-plugin",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "I build, therefore I'm awesome.",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "wp-scripts build",
        "format": "wp-scripts format",
        "lint:css": "wp-scripts lint-style",
        "lint:js": "wp-scripts lint-js",
        "start": "wp-scripts start",
        "packages-update": "wp-scripts packages-update"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8.0.0",
        "npm": ">=6.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@wordpress/scripts": "^20.0.2"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "react-multi-date-picker": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

**The Error**

```
react-dom.min.js?ver=17.0.1:141 Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Comment: Might be more than one copy of React?  WP's block editor, Gutenberg, is React based so Im wondering if React is loaded twice... once from your plugin and once from wordpress for the block editor.

Comment: @mikerojas That's what I was thinking, but I can't seem to find any resources about how to package WP Core's React. I've added my `package.json` file above for reference.